# UITableView superClass for delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A quick question, I am setting a delegate for UITableView and I have a question regarding setting the delegate and dataSource properties. I have noticed that the properties for delegate and dataSource are not available, I was thinking that adopting the  protocols would make them available. But I am now thinking that I maybe have the superclass for my delegate class wrong.

Currently I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    TestDelegate *tempDelegate = [[TestDelegate alloc] init];
    [self setMyDelegate:tempDelegate];
    // setDelegate
    // setDataSource
    [tempDelegate release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

My interface for TestDelegate looks like:

```
@interface TestDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *listData;
    int myCounter;
}
```

Can I ask if the above should be:

```
@interface TestDelegate : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *listData;
    int myCounter;
}
```

gary

**EDIT:** I think it might be on the right track: my delegate superClass should be NSObject, I also have a UITableView in Interface Builder.

I have added @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView; in Xcode and connected this to my UITableView in IB. I can now access the delegate and dataSource properties in Xcode via the IBOutlet.

Comment: THere doesn't seem to be a question there.  What do you mean by "properties for delegate and dataSource are not available"? - a UITableView has those properties.  Also what do you mean by "adopting the protocols would make them available"?

Comment: Hi Paul, I was getting confused, basically I was trying to set UITableView>delegate and UITableView>dataSource inside Xcode but was confused about how to do it. What I was missing was that like all items you add in IB if you want to access them via Xcode you need to create a pointer to the respective object using IBOutlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, there is a difference between **subclassing** `UITableView` and merely conforming to the `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDatasource` protocols.

You would want to subclass `UITableView` if you needed different behavior in the table view itself. -> **Most of the time you will not want to do this**.

`UITableView` has a `delegate` and `dataSource` property, you can assign it to an object that conforms to the respective protocol.

**If you want to have top-level access to the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties, you need to subclass `UITableViewController`.** (do not conform to the delegate protocols if you subclass `UITableViewController`)

Comment: Hi Jacob, your right, I was getting confused with how to access my UITableView in IB via Xcode and went off on a tangent looking for the solution in the wrong place. Your time and comments are much appreciated.